# Add a tooltip to draw container sprite

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a DrawContainer and I want to add a sprite with a tooltip to it, ideally with dynamic content. Unfortunately, the tooltip does not appear at all. How can the code below be corrected?
Thanks in advance.

```
var r = this.getSurface().add({
    type: "rect", strokeStyle: "#9090f0", x: 10, y: 10, width: 40, height: 40
});
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    html: "Tooltip"
});
r.on("mouseover", function() {
    tip.show();
});
```

Comment: Please check (using console.log) whether the event is called.

Comment: I checked, it is not called.

Comment: [Meanwhile, I have checked the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.draw.sprite.Rect.html). Where did you find that a rect sprite would fire a mouseover event?

Comment: I didn't find it. I assumed it is possible. Unfortunately, I haven't found the complete list of allowed events. Anyway, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [spriteevents](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.draw.plugin.SpriteEvents.html) plugin on the draw container, like so

```
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    html: "Tooltip"
});

var s = Ext.create({
    xtype:     'draw',
    renderTo:  document.body,
    width:     400,
    height:    400,
    plugins:   ['spriteevents'],
    sprites:   [
        {
            type:        "rect",
            strokeStyle: "#9090f0",
            x:           10,
            y:           10,
            width:       100,
            height:      100
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        spritemouseover: function (item, event) {
            tip.show();
        },
        spritemouseout:  function (item, event) {
            tip.hide()
        }
    }
});
```